# how to add days in orient db

Tags: sql, database, orientdb

How do we add days to dates in Orient db?

```
select sysdate()+1 from safetyplan;
```

It is giving same output as sysdate().
1 is not getting added. Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Orientdb doc 2.2:

> sysdate() returns the current date time. If executed with no parameters, it
>   returns a Date object, otherwise a string with the requested
>   format/timezone.

So one possible way is to convert date object to long using .asLong() method of date object.Then do the necessary addition.Convert it back to date using .asDate() method.

**Example**:To get a day added to current day use:

```
select sum(sysdate().asLong(),86400000).asDate() from safetyplan;
```

Note:we are adding in milliseconds and 1 day=1000*60*60*24 milliseconds

NB:Thought that this answers may help someone and sorry for answering my own question.

Comment: no need to excuse for answering your question. It's rather nice to solve by your own +1.